# C# implicit conversion error from generic list to Ienumerable

Tags: c#, linq

```
public IEnumerable<XdbActiveDiscipline> GetAllDisciplineDocs(string projectNumber)
{
    try
    {
        // return _MigratorDBContext.XdbActiveDiscipline.Where(x => x.OtProjectNumber == projectNumber && x.IsProcessed==null).ToList();
        var val = _MigratorDBContext.XdbActiveDiscipline.Where(x => x.OtProjectNumber == projectNumber && x.IsProcessed == null).OrderBy(x => x.DocumentReference).GroupBy(x => new { x.DocumentReference, x.DocumentRevisionNumber, x.DocumentRevisionObject })
            .Select(g => new { g, count = g.Count() })
            .SelectMany(t => t.g.Select(b => b)
                .Zip(Enumerable.Range(1, t.count), (j, i) => new
                {
                    j.OtProjectNumber,
                    rn = i
                }))
            .ToList();

        return val;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        return null;
    }
}
```

return val: Throws the error

And the code is written to add a `rownumber()` value at the last of the result set (i.e partition by)

[image]

Comment: VAL IS ANONYMOUS, not XdbActiveDiscipline. change it to: .Zip(Enumerable.Range(1, t.count), (j, i) => new XdbActiveDiscipline(){.......

Comment: Your method expects a concrete type in your `IEnumerable` but you are returning an `anonymous` type - by using `new {}`

Comment: side note; if your method returns an `IEnumerable<something>` there is no need to call `ToList()` on the query result: let the caller do that, if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Val is List of  anonymos , not  List < XdbActiveDiscipline > . Change  return  of the action to this:

```
return val.Select( i=> new XdbActiveDiscipline{
Id=i.Id,
.... and so on
}).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your return value is not `typeof(XdbActiveDiscipline)`. As you can see the error says `missing a cast?` and the method expects an `IEnumerable` of `XdbActiveDiscipline` in return.

The element you are selecting on the `linq` query is an anonymous type different from the expected return, you can see that if you hover over the val when instantiating.